# Android mysql SocketException: Permission Denied

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to create an app that has to get some data from a mysql server.

I know, usually adding the Internet permission to the manifest fixes this problem.

However when I try to do this I get the following error (LogCat display):

```
> 03-05 20:01:41.604: D/ERROR(25938): java.sql.SQLException: Unable to
> connect to any hosts due to exception: java.net.SocketException:
> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Normally I would check my Manifest.xml and put the required code in, however my current manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.speelveldapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
```

There must be something I've missed but I can't figure out what. So if anyone could give me a clue where to look that would be great!

Comment: You can't connect to a remote mysql database. You have to create a web service in front of your remote database and talk to it via something like REST.

Comment: It is possible to connect to a remote (my)SQL server with android. You only need a 3th party *.jar file to make it work (just like you would with regular java). Be aware tough that you should use version 3.0.17 and not 3.1.* (the new version doenst seem to work on sdkversion 9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo;

> <***user***-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

should be

> <***uses***-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Doh! Dyslexia doenst help with programming so it seems.

Comment: @NickOtten It's just a matter of having done the exact same thing enough times to recognize it :)

Comment: Yea i hope so. Anyway thanks a lot for the help! Believe it or not but i've been stuck on that single character for a long (and rather anoying) time.